# Native mail composer has normal status bar in iPhone but mostly blank in iPad

Tags: ios7

I'm using a `UIDocumentInteractionController` in my universal app. On an iPhone, when a user is presented with the interaction controller and they select the "Mail" option, a native Mail composer window is presented that still shows the full status bar (carrier, the time and the battery life indicator). When the same code executes on the iPad version, the native Mail composer window slides up and then right when it reaches the top, the status bar goes completely black except for the green bar that is normally inside the battery.

Is there anything I can do to control the appearance of the status bar when the native mail composer window opens?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here you can change your status bar style, Hope it will help for you.]

Here you can change your status bar style in you App info, Hope it will help for you.